# RoboVM building error. Double checked everything

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, libgdx, robovm

[image]I spent 2 days trying to figure this problem out, and just can't, so I'm really looking into any thoughts about fixing this.

So, 
I trying to launch my IOSLauncher with RoboVM tool. I did everything what's necessary for IOS configurations. Double check everything. For simplier understanding I'm adding some photos.
Here are the problems :
Firstly I had consider mounting a disk. I did it.

[image]

And after that an unknown error appears 
[image]

UPDATE running with STACKTRACE

[image]

[image]

UPDATE 2
With --info
[image]

With --debug
[image]

UPDATE 3

### Running with --stacktrace, check causing problem.

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbSut.png)
[image]

UPDATE 4 (I'm willing the last one)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfIlR.png)
CAUSED BY:

[image]

Comment: Add --stacktrace to your build command and show result please.

Comment: @ThomasPronold Thanks you so much for stopping by and helping. Please tell me how to add it, because never heard of it yet. Ready to do anything you say to fix it.

Comment: Ok, try to use the commandline: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#running-the-ios-project. F.e:: gradlew ios:launchIOSDevice --stacktrace

Comment: @ThomasPronold Thanks, now I learnt how to control my project through terminal. Did with stacktrace. Added photos. Please check.

Comment: Do you get more information when you use --info or --debug instead of --stacktrace?. Search the compiler error output for more information. Seems to be a problem in your code, maybe some old robovm <7 stuff. Right click ios project -> gradle ->refresh all might reveal the error in Eclipse.

Comment: @ThomasPronold yes, bro, still can't figure it out, what's wrong.

Added photos. Check it out, loads of respect.

Comment: With your SpriteAccessor and ValueAccessor class is something wrong.It looks to me that the Tween extension is not really prepared to work with iOS. I never worked with Tween, so look at their wiki/manual.

Comment: Just found: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine cannot see any instructions for iOS. Maybe you are out of luck and Tween does not support iOS. Or just try adding it to iOS project like you did for Android/Desktop.

Comment: @ThomasPronold   I think I fixed problem with Universal-Tween-Engine, but that wasn't the case.  Now i ran with stracktrace and check the causing is the error it interesting - Caused by: : /Users/macpro/.m2/repository/org/robovm/robovm-dist/1.2.0/unpacked/robovm-1.2.0/bin does not exist.

Comment: Go to /Users/macpro/.m2/repository/org/robovm/robovm-dist/1.2.0/ folder. There should be a robovm-1.2.0.zip or similiar name, unpack this zip to /Users/macpro/.m2/repository/org/robovm/robovm-dist/1.2.0/unpacked

Comment: Did it! Solved that problem! Thanks for finding the answer. But the IOSLAUNCHER still can't be launched... Added updated photos of running with stacktrace. Thanks you @ThomasPronold for helping, I will text you my game url, to try, brother!

Comment: At this place I recommend to update your libgdx and robovm to the latest version before hunting errors on very old 1.2.0 robovm version. We are at 1.8.0 now.

Comment: @ThomasPronold Thank you so much man, everything is working now, thanks for your time! Appreciate it!